# Undefined reference error while compiling Qt hello world program

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to compile a Qt hello world program. I am using Qt 5.2.0 on Windows 64 bit.
This is my code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
 qDebug() << "Hello world";
 return a.exec();
 }
```

When i run the application i get the following run time errors:

```
 mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/test/qt_creator_projects/build-QtTest-    TestLocal_PC-Debug'
 g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\QtTest -    

 I"D:\Qt\5.2.0\msvc2012_64\include" -I"D:\Qt\5.2.0\msvc2012_64\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -   
 I"." -I"D:\Qt\5.2.0\msvc2012_64\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o ..\QtTest\main.cpp
  g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\QtTest.exe debug/main.o  -   

  LD:\Qt\5.2.0\msvc2012_64\lib -lQt5Cored 
 debug/main.o: In function `main':
  C:\Users\test\qt_creator_projects\build-QtTest-TestLocal_PC-  
  Debug/../QtTest/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN16QCoreApplicationC1ERiPPci'

  C:\Users\test\qt_creator_projects\build-QtTest-TestLocal_PC-  Debug/../QtTest/main.cpp:7:   undefined reference to `_imp___ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv'

  Makefile.Debug:77: recipe for target 'debug\QtTest.exe' failed
  C:\Users\test\qt_creator_projects\build-QtTest-TestLocal_PC-  

  Debug/../QtTest/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN16QCoreApplicationD1Ev'
 mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/test/qt_creator_projects/build-QtTest-  TestLocal_PC-Debug'
 Makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
 C:\Users\test\qt_creator_projects\build-QtTest-TestLocal_PC-Debug/../QtTest/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN16QCoreApplicationD1Ev'
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\QtTest.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
16:37:34: The process "D:\pen drive data\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project QtTest (kit: TestLocal PC)
When executing step 'Make'
```

.pro file

```
   QT       += core

   QT       -= gui
   TARGET = QtTest
   CONFIG   += console
   CONFIG   -= app_bundle

   TEMPLATE = app


   SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I want to use Qt with MinGW .I am currently using Qt creatore for 64 bit Visual Studio 2012 compiler. Since 64 bit MinGW is not available in the downloads for 5.2.0

Can someone help me solve these reference errors?

Comment: "I am currently using Qt creatore for 64 bit Visual Studio 2012 compiler." - you're not, that's mingw's GCC you're using (g++), trying  to link to MSVC versions of the libraries judging from the paths visible in the log. Recheck your settings, you've got a mixup which can't work.

Comment: From the qt website I downloaded the VS 2012 version (64 bit windows). I do not have visual studio installed on my machine. So i want to use the MingGW compiler instead..Is that possible? I have added the compiler for the same in the build and run kit

Comment: Also, when I create a new project now and try and run, it says "Qt creator needs a compiler setup to be build"

Comment: I have added the MinGW compiler kit. It's only after that I am getting undefined reference erors

Comment: You cannot use the VS versions of the libraries with GCC. If you want to use MinGW, you need to download that edition. As for "needs a compiler setup", you'll find a lot of information about what to do about it (here and elsewhere). But you have to make sure you have the right binaries for your toolchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you download a VS2012 version of Qt if you don't have, well, VS2012?

Download a version that matches the exact compiler you have. If there is none, download the sources and compile it yourself.

If you want to avoid the complications of self-compilation, then VS2012 Express is perfectly adequate to develop with Qt. It's the same compiler as the paid-for versions, and if you develop using Qt Creator, then you really don't care for whatever limitations the express edition IDE might have. It works great.

Another possibility is to use the mingw build of Qt. During setup, you can enable the installation of the MinGW 4.8.0 toolchain. This gives you a complete development environment, with the IDE, the Qt headers and binaries, and a toolchain.